# How to get an image URL of Umbraco members

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I have some members in my Umbraco website , and i want to display some details of the members such as : Member Brief,  Member Webiste  , Member picture .

So the issue that i have is wow to get the member image URL (which surrounded by the red circle in the below image ) 
 ?

[image]

The problem I have is How to get the member image ?

I tried to use the main method to display an image  from Umbraco , which I use always to display images ,

```
@{
var memberImage= memberItem.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("memberImage");
if (memberImage!= null)
{
    <p>@memberImage.Url</p>
    <img src="@memberImage.Url" />
}
```

}

but it didn't work , and i got this error

> 'IMember' doesn't contain a definition for 'GetPropertyValue' and the best extension method overload 'PublishedContentExtensions.GetPropertyValue(PublishedContent,string)'

I changed GetPropertyValue to GetValue , i get null value .

Any one have an idea of how to display member image on the website ?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates/retrieves the `memberItem` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my question is :

1- Use File Upload  property instead of Media picker .

2- Use the below code to retrieve the image URL :

```
    var memberImage = memberItem.GetValue<string>("memberImage");
     <img src="@(memberImage != null ? memberImage : "")" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a "simple" .GetPropertyValue("yourPropertyName") instead, maybe? I don't think you will get IPublishedContent from a member property - most likely the property will be an Image ID/UDI or the image URL.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your reply .. 
When i make it " .GetPropertyValue("yourPropertyName") " , i get this error :
'IMember' doesn't contain a definition for 'GetPropertyValue'  

As i mentioned that in my question .